# ArchUnit: Create a rule based on class imports

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

I would like to create an ArchUnit rule which will not allow to use so called starred (*) imports in my project. Can I achieve this in ArchUnit?

Comment: https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/124 => *"You can per se not do any checks of imports with ArchUnit, since ArchUnit operates on bytecode and import statements live only in source code (and vanish on compile)."*

Comment: as any other libs for java, yes you can use it. you might have some other issue. please read carefully the errors. But, I'd also recommend to DON'T use a wildcard in imports to avoid an issue that is described in prev comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CheckStyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) rule [AvoidStarImport](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#AvoidStarImport) for this.